# Adding a lambda expression has resulted in a strange error when attempting to compile

Tags: c#, lambda

So currently there is a piece of code which looks like this...

```
string name = GetValues(sequenceOfCodes, 0, IDtoMatch, 1)[0];
```

I just updated the following line to be

```
string name = sequenceOfCodes
                  .Select(x => x[0])
                      .Where(x => x == IDtoMatch)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Which should hopefully return the same thing.

sequenceOfCodes is a `List<List<String>>` and the `IDtoMatch` is also a `string`.

So hopefully this all seems fine.

However when I go to compile I get an odd error

```
The type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' is defined in an assembly 
that is not referenced. 

You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

And when I take my newly added code away it compiles fine and runs... So why is it just because I have added a `lambda expression` does it think that I it needs a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`?

Just to state that this is a **console** application. **Not** a winforms application.

-----------UPDATE----------

Ok, So I have found that a one of the references does reference the System.Windows.Forms, which I is really disappointing as this is core code and should not have dependencies like this :(

However I still wonder why the error did not appear before until after I added my line of code.

To confirm, If I remove my code I can close VS down and restart and rebuild and all is fine.
If I add my line of code and close down and restart, etc. The error will reappear on rebuild.

Very strange error to me.

Thanks guys for all your help

Comment: @James why x == IDtoMatch is not correct??

Comment: No he doesnt, since IDtoMatch is a string, not a type.

Comment: @James `x == IDToMatch` is correct.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel yeah just realised you mention `IDtoMatch` is also a `string` - word of advice, try not to label variables like they are types...

Comment: @James, `IDtoMatch` can be a property, and in that case the casing is correct.

Comment: Also sorry to be a pain, but I don't necessarily want my code reviewed just would like help with resolving my error. thanks

Comment: it has been removed by James :))

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yeah casing wise, still quite misleading with the `I` prefix, at first glance as I assumed `IDtoMatch` was an interface type.

Comment: well I did put "IDtoMatch is also a string"

Comment: @SecretSquirrel it would be worth using "Go to definition" (`f12`) on each of `.Select`, `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault` to investigate exactly where those extension methods are coming from; are they the `System.Linq.Enumerable` methods? or are they perhaps coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @MarcGravell All methods are from `System.Linq.Enumerable`

Comment: @James no, read again

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I can't actually see any reason why there is a dependency on `System.Windows.Forms` here, are you sure there isn't *any* other code that could possibly be referencing `ComboBox`? Perhaps a referenced library?

Comment: @Shaamaan I first use a select which will give me an `IEnumerable<String>` which I then use a `Where` on to find the match. The other way round would not work.

Comment: What references are in the project?

Comment: @James Yes, this is my issue. I cannot see any reason either. But if I remove my statement, the error goes away and the console successfully runs.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel you could get rid of the `Select` altogether as your `Where` could just use `x[0]` in the check. Anyway, to your problem, are you referencing any other external libs?

Comment: @Stefan Lets just say `GetValues()` is a big horrible method used else where throughout. But for this instance where only the first value is of a concern and that's all that is needed it was just a bit overkill to fire off the `GetValues` method

Comment: Look guys I don't want to seem like I am not grateful, but I don't need my code reviewing, unless its directly related to fixing the issue I have raised. Thanks

Comment: If you close Visual Studio completely, delete the bin and obj folders and any ".suo" file, then rebuild do you still get the error? Also, what happens if you add that code to a newly-created test app?

Comment: @Secret, did you install extensions to Visual Studio, or are you using the "vanilla" environment?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi extensions have been installed, power tools, etc.

Comment: @Secret, then can you reproduce the problem after temporarily disabling all these extensions (or running VS with the `/SafeMode` command line switch)?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that one of the other projects does reference windows forms. My *guess* is that this project also declares some extension methods that are in scope (given your `using` directives), and which the compiler needs to explore for overload resolution - presumably of the `Where`, `Select` or `FirstOrDefault` methods; meaning: it can't decide that the *best* overload of these is the `System.Linq.Enumerable` one until it has compared it to the other candidates, and it can't do that without being able to understand the types used in the competing method signatures.

Or in other words: is there a `Select`, `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` custom extension method that mentions `ComboBox` ?